# if-else condition check in rails state machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I am developing application in rails , where i have made use of state_machine (https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/).

> Here i wanted to check condition in one state , based on condition
>   state changes from another state . (i.e consider **state1 , state2 and
>   state3 are states if(a>b) {state1 => state2 }else {state1 =>state3})** ,

i wanted to know how this will be accomplished in state machine .
 kindly help me out in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In state_machine, you define events that change the state of the underlying object.  You can also set the state attribute to the state that you want.

In your case you'd do:

```
a.state = a > b ? "state2" : "state3"
a.save!
```

You can also check the state with:

```
a.state1?
```

What you should do is define an event that describes the transition from state1 to state2 or state3. For instance:

```
state_machines :state, initial: :state1 do
  ... 

  event :go_to_state2 do
    transition state1: :state2
  end

  event :go_to_state3 do
    transition state1: :state3
  end

  ...
end
```

Then, you transition state like this:

```
if a > b
  a.go_to_state2!
else
  a.go_to_state3!
end
```

Using the events are a lot cleaner way of manipulating the state.  This is all covered in the [Readme on the plugin's github page](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/)

Comment: thanks andrew , you mean to say define separate event for each path i got the idea.